# Install rsync 3.1.1 on systemd

Tags: rsync, systemd

I have CentOS 7 and it comes with Rsync 3.0.9.
I downloaded the 3.1.1 el7 rpm and installed with rpm -Uvh.

Now the daemon refuse to start. I tried to create :

> /usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyncd.service

```
[Unit]
Description=A program for synchronizing files over a network
After=syslog.target network.target
ConditionPathExists=/etc/rsyncd.conf

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/rsyncd
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach "$OPTIONS"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

No luck :

```
/bin/systemctl status  rsyncd.service
● rsyncd.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-04-21 15:27:00 EDT; 56min ago
 Main PID: 1452 (code=exited, status=20)
```

Note those referenced file in the configuration exist:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1699 Feb  4 14:27 /etc/rsyncd.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11 Apr 21 16:09 /etc/sysconfig/rsyncd
```

Comment: What 3.1.1 el7 rpm?

Comment: I'd go back using `3.0.9`, unless you're _REALLY_ need something from 3.1.1, it looks like rpm that you're using is packaged differently from the one that ships with distributive.

Comment: rsync-3.1.1-1.el7.rfx.x86_64.rpm, I need the new --chown option.

Comment: @Bastien974 can't `--owner` be use instead?

Comment: @Alexus, I need the owner to be different on the destination. (note that -o is required for --chown to work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that `systemctl daemon-reload` is required to load the service.
After doing that, it worked right away.

Answer (score 3):

I've got 3.1.1 under fedora 22.

The requisite config files for `rsyncd` are in the `rsync-daemon` package. I've listed the files in each package below.

I'd just install the extra package.

But, I did notice a typo in your config file ...

Change:

```
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/rsyncd
```

Into:

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/rsyncd
```

---

Here's a list of files in the `rsync` package:

```
/usr/bin/rsync
/usr/share/doc/rsync
/usr/share/doc/rsync/NEWS
/usr/share/doc/rsync/OLDNEWS
/usr/share/doc/rsync/README
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/Makefile
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/atomic-rsync
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/cvs2includes
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/deny-rsync
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/file-attr-restore
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/files-to-excludes
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/git-set-file-times
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/instant-rsyncd
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/logfilter
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/lsh
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/lsh.sh
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/mapfrom
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/mapto
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/mnt-excl
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/munge-symlinks
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/rrsync
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/rsync-no-vanished
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/rsync-slash-strip
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/rsyncstats
/usr/share/doc/rsync/support/savetransfer.c
/usr/share/doc/rsync/tech_report.tex
/usr/share/licenses/rsync
/usr/share/licenses/rsync/COPYING
/usr/share/man/man1/rsync.1.gz
```

---

Here's a list of files in the `rsync-daemon` package:

```
/etc/rsyncd.conf
/etc/sysconfig/rsyncd
/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyncd.service
/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyncd.socket
/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyncd@.service
/usr/share/man/man5/rsyncd.conf.5.gz
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> I tried to force install rsync-daemon on my Centos 7, given that it's just text file, I took a chance and ignored the dependency.

I'm not sure what dependency you mean, but I looked at the rpm's `.spec` file and it lists `systemd-units`, but I can't find an rpm for that.

> No luck.

Not quite sure what this means. Did the files extract/install or not? Can you do `ls -l` on them? As a last resort, did you try `rpm --nodeps --force`?

Given an `.rpm` file, it is possible to manually extract files using `rpm2cpio` [should be part of the already installed `rpm` package] and either `cpio` or `pax` [which is very similar to `tar`, but understands *both* `tar` and `cpio` format archives].

I've usually had better luck using `pax`. It has its own rpm [to install: `yum install pax`]. In fact, I've never gotten the `rpm2cpio/cpio` combination to work correctly for extraction.

To list an rpm file using `pax`:

```
rpm2cpio rpmfile | pax -v
```

To extract an rpm file using `pax`:

```
rpm2cpio rpmfile | pax -v -r
```

> I also tried to extract the file directly, but it still refuses to start.

You may have to consult some logfiles, such as `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/audit/audit.log`, `/var/log/secure`, and may have to use the `journalctl` program to view the systemd log.

You might have some [silly] `selinux` security restriction that has to be fixed. You may have to run `restorecon` on the config files.

Also, you may have to add something to the `/etc` files as it may be `rsync` itself that doesn't want to start (vs. `systemd` not starting `rsync`).

Below are the contents of the `rsync-daemon` files, *except* for the man page file [which is way too large to include here]. The man page file can be found here: http://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyncd.conf

---

/etc/rsyncd.conf

```
# /etc/rsyncd: configuration file for rsync daemon mode

# See rsyncd.conf man page for more options.

# configuration example:

# uid = nobody
# gid = nobody
# use chroot = yes
# max connections = 4
# pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
# exclude = lost+found/
# transfer logging = yes
# timeout = 900
# ignore nonreadable = yes
# dont compress   = *.gz *.tgz *.zip *.z *.Z *.rpm *.deb *.bz2

# [ftp]
#        path = /home/ftp
#        comment = ftp export area
```

---

/etc/sysconfig/rsyncd

```
OPTIONS=""
```

---

/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyncd.service

```
[Unit]
Description=fast remote file copy program daemon
ConditionPathExists=/etc/rsyncd.conf

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/rsyncd
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach "$OPTIONS"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyncd@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=fast remote file copy program daemon
ConditionPathExists=/etc/rsyncd.conf

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/rsyncd
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rsync --daemon --no-detach "$OPTIONS"
StandardInput=socket
```

---

/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyncd.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=Rsync Server Socket
Conflicts=rsyncd.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=873
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Comment: Why do you suggest changing `EnvironmentFile=`? It looks correct as it was.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I extracted the file from the rpm and it didn't match OP's. But, my first advice was to install the `rsync-daemon` package which has other files as well. (i.e.) The error message didn't say _which_ file was missing. After that, OP can start tweaking if things still don't work.

Comment: @CraigEstey, where do I get rsync-daemon ?

Comment: Normally, it's part of your distro, so `yum install rsync-daemon` should work. Also, you can find RPMs for the rsync-daemon here: https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=rsync-daemon These contain mostly text/config files so not much variance. These will need a manual install with either `yum` [newer is `dnf`] or `rpm`. Try one until you find the best match for your system.

Comment: I tried to force install rsync-daemon on my Centos 7, given that it's just text file, I took a chance and ignored the dependency. No luck. I also tried to extract the file directly, but it still refuses to start.

Comment: I have the exact same files, but keep getting : `Failed to start rsyncd.service: Unit rsyncd.service failed to load: No such file or directory.` If I execute manually `rsync --daemon`, it works. Only thing I see with journalctl is : `polkitd[2305]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process[...]` and `polkitd[2305]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process[...]` which seems normal.

Comment: I think you'll have to turn on systemd debugging. See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_debug_Systemd_problems and the embedded upstream link. I'd add the boot param `systemd.log_level=debug` and see. Also, you could change the rsync.service files to point to a script [that you write] that runs rsync under strace. The script can also touch a unique file (e.g. `/tmp/i_was_started`) to confirm whether systemd gave up before invoking rsync or not. You may also wish to `rsync --version` to verify it got installed. You could rebuild from source. Where did the original rsync 3.1.1 rpm come from?