# sync system rpmdb to a local copy

Tags: rpm

On our business servers, for various reasons we want to use rpm packages, but we can't install the rpm package into the system database (permissions, multiple instances, etc).  So we have created our own local rpmdb and install packages as non-root and with a --dbpath argument.  So currently our local db may have only 10 packages in it.  This works well, allows for non-root install, and allows for multiple instances of the same package because multiple rpmdbs are being used.  The drawback is everything must be installed with --nodeps because our local databases don't see any of the packages installed at the system level.

In an attempt to solve the --nodeps problem, there are several ways I can initialize my local databases with the current system db (simply copy /var/lib/rpm/Packages and rebuild for example).  Then installing our application packages on top should allow us to fully use dependencies.  But the problem is how to keep the system packages in sync after the first copy.  If the admins install a system patch, only the system rpmdb will be updated.  I'm looking for some method to write a nightly batch job that will compare updates and apply the database only updates to our local copies.

Any thoughts of what commands might be used to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help.
Brian

Answer (score 0):

`--nodeps`, relocatable packages, and manually managing the Berkeley DB, are each painful. And you want to do all three? I don't recommend this, it is going backwards 20 years in package management. [Very few packages out of Fedora or EL are relocatable](https://serverfault.com/questions/773984/why-are-some-rpms-not-relocatable), as it just can't be managed by yum. In addition, nodeps means you may get into dependencies not easily fixable by yum.

---

Give users a "host" for each instance they need. VMs, containers, chroots (`yum --installroot`), any of these may less expensive than time fighting with RPM.

Automate provisioning. Have procedures where users can propose changes in the package set that get reviewed in a timely manner. Possibly give some users privilege to test instances, so they can try stuff without breaking anything important.

Repackage anything to not require relocation or alternate rpmdb. Move to non-conflicting paths, make separate packages with version numbers in Name. In general, follow Fedora RPM packaging guidelines. Then packages can be managed with yum.

Comment: Thank you for your comments,  but trying to manage all those instances would be hard.   We are building our own relocatable packages and manually installing with rpm; leaving yum / dnf for system packages.   Maybe eventually a vm host for every instance in every development,  integration, production,  and disaster recovery  environment but we aren't there now.  If it's too hard to copy & sync the system database,  we will just stay with nodeps.   But thank you for the advice.